# rosbag duration

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been tried to record a bag for a given duration and it seems that the arguments are ignored, so it still records until I hit Ctrl+C.

I'm running this command (but it fails for any topic/s):

```
rosbag record --duration 10 /camera/image_color
```

on ros-electric, ubuntu oneiric.

Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12597/rosbag-duration/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-01-11**:
I want to use it for multiple topics, publishing at different frequencies, so -l NUM_MSGS is useless, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just created [this enhancement ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5335) to request this feature.

**UPDATE** The ticket is now solved and closed!

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like [`rosbag record`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#record) does not currently provide a `--duration` option.

As you pointed out, that would sometimes be quite useful. You might consider opening an enhancement ticket to add that feature.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1